# Firebase Console: How do I delete a table?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I noticed that firebase is not showing the buttons to delete a table when it has a lot of data in it:

My `location-orders` table with a lot of data in it:

[image]

As opposed to my `users` table which has 1 thing in it:

[image]

How do I delete the `locations-orders` table?

Answer (score 3):

When my database is large using <kbd>x</kbd> is not that useful (to be honest for some reason it doesn't appear after some number of rows for me).

So, the easiest way I've found is to use [firebase cli](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

First install it (You need node.js installed) with `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Login to your firebase project with `firebase login`.

Remove data with:

`firebase database:remove / --project your-project-id`

`/` here is location of data to delete so for your case you need:

`firebase database:remove /locations-orders --project your-project-id`

Answer (score 0):

Given the amount of data, your database dashboard has switched to static, read-only mode. You cannot modify the data in this mode, so will have to get back into interactive mode first.

If you click on `location-orders` you will get a view that starts at that level.

In this new view you will see an <kbd>x</kbd> over `location-orders`. Clicking that <kbd>x</kbd>, deletes the `location-orders`.

Comment: This will only work provided that `location-orders` itself does not contain so many records that static read-only mode is activated, otherwise the CLI is the way to go

Answer (score -1):

You can use the postman or some auxiliary tool to execute api and make the call rest:

[postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3a2k.png)

soon after it returns to the firebase database and its table is enabled for deletion.